# c++ default array size override with command line arguments

Tags: c++, arrays, command-line-arguments

I saw one question on similar lines 
[Specify Array from Command Line Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901944/specify-array-from-command-line-argument)

Although my problem is bit different.

I have multiple files implementing arrays of same size (NOC_SIZE). My program has a default mode and a user mode (command line arguments). I gave the 'unsigned int NOC_SIZE = 16;' line in my code before the start of main function. In another header file I declared a struct (noc_package) with parameter 'static unsigned int NOC_SIZE;'. This header file in included in all files where ever required.

But in the files where I have declared an array (int arr[noc_package :: NOC_SIZE]) it gives an error saying array bound not an integer.

Can somebody suggest a way around this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't support variable-length arrays.

You're better of using an `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<int> arr(noc_package::NOC_SIZE);
```

Comment: True. But even after I provide the default size (which should be overridden, if required, by command line arguments) should not it work?

Comment: @Gurunath no, it shouldn't even work with the default size, since it appears it's not a compile-time constant.

Comment: I know you are right, but i thought there will be some solution to it. I can't use vector as the array I am creating is actually of predefined data structure (SystemC, HDL language based on C++). I even tried unsigned int NOC_SIZE = DEFAULT; with #define DEFAULT 16, but same result.

Comment: @Gurunath same result because what you're asking is impossible. I don't see how the array you want to create is a predefined data structure, since you're only just creating it...

Comment: If the "command line" that you are talking about is the command line of your executable, then no, you simply cannot.  The executable has already been built with the array size preset.  If it is the command line of the compiler, yes it is possible.  Why do you think you cannot use a vector?

Comment: I am talking about the int main(int argc, char* argv[]). About using vector, I think I should apologize to both of you. I will try to implement it. In case of doubt I will come back. Thanks.

Comment: @Gurunath great! that's what you should do.

Comment: Following the suggestion, i used 'vector<cdma_data> data_in_temp(noc_package::NOC_SIZE);'. I got the error saying _error: ‘noc_package::NOC_SIZE’ is not a type_. I even tried with an number (16), error were _error: expected identifier before numeric constant_ and _error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant_. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Gurunath you're not including the files that define `cdma_data` and `noc_package`.

Comment: Actually I have included them. In fact when I try 'vector<cdma_data> data_in_temp;', it works. And wherever I am using 'noc_package::NOC_SIZE', other than vector, it works too!

Comment: @Gurunath did you `#include <vector>`?

Comment: Of course, I included that. As I said vector declaration wo any size was getting compiled but with size not!

Comment: @Gurunath then the problem is `noc_package :: NOC_SIZE` - what type is it?

Comment: The type is 'unsigned int'. But other than that why won't it work with 'vector<cdma_data> data_in_temp(16);'?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Hi there! Extremely sorry for replying late (ubuntu problem---12.10!!) Anyways I did some experiments with an independent code and whatever you said worked. Also I created a vector of pointer to objects as that is my final goal. I learned there that it is better if i make a vector without any size predefined. So I will be coding accordingly and in case of any problem I will come here!! Thank you very much for your suggestions!!